# How to get the first input field from noteList and how to check for

Tags: javascript

[image: console screenshoot]

I would like to check if a div contains an input-field. The div is created by code, so there is no use of querySelectors. The div is here named to.
I tried the following code without success.

```
  console.log("TOOOOOOOchildNodes:",to.childNodes);
  console.log("to: ",to);
  for (const entry of to.childNodes.entries()) {
    console.log("entrys: ",entry);
    console.log("has: ",entry.indexOf('input'))
    //console.log("contains: ",entry.contains('input')) //Uncaught TypeError: entry.contains is not a function
  }
```

Comment: Can you add relevant "*[mcve]*" JavaScript that generates the elements you're searching. and explain when - and in response to what event/interaction - you need to search for the `<input>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try checking the `nodeName` property of each node:

```
console.log("TOOOOOOOchildNodes:",to.childNodes);
console.log("to: ",to);
for (const entry of to.childNodes) {
  if (entry.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
    console.log("Found an input element:", entry);
    // Perform actions on the input element if needed
  }
}
```